# How to import `snakebite` package in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hadoop, snakebite

I'm trying to connect to Hadoop (HDFS) using Python. I'm using `snakebite` package for establishing connection. I installed it successfully, but when I'm trying to import it, it gives error as follows:

```
from snakebite.client import Client
client = Client('localhost', 9000)
```

**Error:**

> File "C:\pythonNJ\lib\site-packages\snakebite\client.py", line 1473 
>   baseTime = min(time * (1L << retries), cap);

Is there a way to solve it or can someone please tell me how to establish connection by another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [its README](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite/blob/master/README.md):

> Snakebite requires python2 (python3 is not supported yet)

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, can you recommend me any better package alternative to Snakebite for hadoop connection in Python 3.

Comment: @David, software recommendations are off-topic here and I'm not very experienced with Hadoop. But it looks like there are [some options](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+3+hadoop). Pick something and give it a try. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A Python 3 fork has been created since then, [snakebite-py3](https://pypi.org/project/snakebite-py3/).

`pip install snakebite-py3`